# numpy fastest way to transform an array's elements to their frequency

Tags: python, numpy

As the title said, I am looking for a way to transform an array so it will be the array of frequency of its proper elements.

I found `np.count` and `np.histogram` but it's not what I am looking for

Something like:

From:

```
array_ = np.array([0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,2,0])
```

To:

```
array_ = np.array([8,8,8,2,8,8,2,8,8,2,2,8])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `array_` contain large values?  `np.bincount(array_)[array_]` does what you need for this example, but it'll be inefficient if you have large values in your original `array_`.

Comment: Is using pandas an option available to you? If so you could use `pd.Series(array_).map(pd.value_counts(array_)).values`. This hashtable-based approach is reasonably quick - still much slower than the super-fast `bincount` method Mark Dickinson suggests, but significantly quicker than `unique` and quicker again than `Counter` (on my machine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the values in your array are nonnegative integers which aren't too large, you can use [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html).  Using your original array as an index into the `bincount` result gives your desired output.

```
>>> array_ = np.array([0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,2,0])
>>> np.bincount(array_)
array([8, 2, 2])
>>> np.bincount(array_)[array_]
array([8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 2, 8])
```

Bear in mind that the result of `np.bincount` has size `max(array_) + 1`, so if your array has large values this approach is inefficient: you end up creating a very large intermediate result.

An alternative approach that should be efficient even with large or negative inputs is to use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html#numpy.unique) with the `return_inverse` and `return_counts` arguments, as follows:

```
>>> array_ = np.array([0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,2,0])
>>> _, inv, counts = np.unique(array_, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
>>> counts[inv]
array([8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 2, 8])
```

Note that the `return_counts` argument is new in NumPy 1.9.0, so you'll need an up-to-date version of NumPy. If you don't have NumPy 1.9.0, all is not lost!  You can still use the `return_inverse` argument of `np.unique`, which gives you back an array of small integers in the same arrangement as your original one.  That new array is now in perfect shape for `bincount` to work on it efficiently:

```
>>> array_ = np.array([0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,2,0])
>>> _, inverse = np.unique(array_, return_inverse=True)
>>> np.bincount(inverse)[inverse]
array([8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 2, 8])
```

Another example, with larger `array_` contents:

```
>>> array_ = np.array([0, 71, 598, 71, 0, 0, 243])
>>> _, inverse = np.unique(array_, return_inverse=True)
>>> inverse
array([0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2])
>>> np.bincount(inverse)[inverse]
array([3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1])
```

All of these solutions work in pure NumPy, so they should be significantly more efficient than a solution that goes via a Python `Counter` or `dict`.  As always, though, if efficiency is a concern then you should profile to find out what's most suitable.  Note in particular that `np.unique` is doing a sort under the hood, so its theoretical complexity is higher than that of the pure `np.bincount` solution.  Whether that makes a difference in practice is impossible to say without timing.
So let's do some timing, using IPython's `timeit` (this is on Python 3.4).  First we'll define functions for the operations we need:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np; from collections import Counter

In [2]: def freq_bincount(array):
   ...:     return np.bincount(array)[array]
   ...: 

In [3]: def freq_unique(array):
   ...:     _, inverse, counts = np.unique(array, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
   ...:     return counts[inverse]
   ...: 

In [4]: def freq_counter(array):
   ...:     c = Counter(array)
   ...:     return np.array(list(map(c.get, array)))
   ...:
```

Now we create a test array:

```
In [5]: test_array = np.random.randint(100, size=10**6)
```

And then we do some timings. Here are the results on my machine:

```
In [6]: %timeit freq_bincount(test_array)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.69 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit freq_unique(test_array)
10 loops, best of 3: 166 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit freq_counter(test_array)
1 loops, best of 3: 317 ms per loop
```

There's an order-of-magnitude difference between the `np.bincount` approach and the `np.unique` approach. The `Counter` approach from @Kasramvd's solution is somewhat slower than the `np.unique` approach, but that could change on a different machine or with different versions of Python and NumPy: you should test with data that are appropriate for your use-case.

Answer (score 3):

As a fast approach you can use `colections.Counter` which is the more pythonic way for getting the frequency of an iterable items :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array_ = np.array([0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,2,0])
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c=Counter(array_)
>>> np.array(map(c.get,array_))
array([8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 2, 2, 8])
```